# Prevent export of foreign key for a specific relation

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I looking for a way to prevent doctrine from exporting the foreign keys for specific relations. For example:

```
Item:
  connection: doctrine
  #attributes:
  #  export: tables
  columns:
    store_id: integer(4)
    shelf_id: integer(4)
  relations:
    Store:
      local: store_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Items
    Shelf:
      local: shelf_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Items

Shelf:
  connection: doctrine
  columns:
    name: string(255)

Store:
  connection: store
  columns:
    name: string(255)
```

Here, if I build this schema, doctrine would generate 2 foreign keys for Item table:

```
ALTER TABLE item ADD CONSTRAINT item_store_id_store_id FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(id);
ALTER TABLE item ADD CONSTRAINT item_shelf_id_shelf_id FOREIGN KEY (shelf_id) REFERENCES shelf(id);
```

If you uncomment 'attributes' section, doctrine won't create any. Where as I only need `item_shelf_id_shelf_id` constraint. The reason I want it is because Item and Shelf tables are in the same database, and Store is in different database - the foreign key for it simply won't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, this thread says foreign keys are supported between databases : http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,150829,200251#msg-200251 So the problem might rather be that the generated sql does not contain the db name.
The SQL is build in `Doctrine_Export::getForeignKeyBaseDeclaration`, which contains these lines:

```
        if ( ! isset($definition['foreignTable'])) {
            throw new Doctrine_Export_Exception('Foreign reference table missing from definition.');
        }
```

So adding a `foreignTable` key containing your database name in your schema.yml might help, if the database is on the same server.

Comment: I really want it database agnostic. People say they use relations between tables in diffrent databases, but I can't figure out the right configuration for that.